# Does any one know a model or set number for my son's broken piece?

Tags: part-identification, piece-information, clone-brands

It's Mega Blocks, a small blue piece Spiderman retractable web where you push a button on the little block and the string recoils back inside the block. All I can get is it's Spiderman retractable web something, but Mega Blocks can't help without a model number or set number.

Comment: Could you post a photo? Someone might recognize it right away from that.

Comment: Here is a mega construx spider man that shoots “webs”, but from the tiny pictures it looks more like a ball than a web: https://www.megabrands.com/en-us/shop/amazing-spider-man/spider-man-techbot

Answer (score 4):

Without seeing a picture it is difficult to determine exactly what you have, but after a bit of research I think you have [MEGA BLOKS set #1916: Spider-Man Super Tech Hero](http://www.blokcity.com/wiki/1916_Spider-Man_Super_Tech_Hero) from 2004.

[image]